# How do convert a PIL Image to JSON serializable string and Vice versa?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have PIL Image and I want to convert it to a string that is JSON serializable and then I want to convert it back to the PIL Image as it was. I have literally read hundreds of questions and answers on StackOverflow but nobody could help me what I want to do.

Some answers say to use `tostring()` method from PIL which is actually now depreciated and is `tobytes()` now and it returns bytes object which I can't directly put into JSON.

Then some of them used `base64.b64encode()` which also returns `bytes` object and is still not JSON compatible.

Mind that I don't wish to store the string directly into a file, I want to make it JSON compatible and then convert it back to PIL Image as it was.

And Yes, I don't want to save it with `Image.save()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) a `b64encode`d bytes object to a string, i.e.

```
>>> image = b"1234567890"
>>> base64.b64encode(image)
b'MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA=='    # bytes
>>> base64.b64encode(image).decode()
'MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA=='     # string
```

As a side note you can also use [`b85encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b85encode) to save space.

Answer (score 1):

From Selcuk's answer I created a string and was able to convert it back to image, I did:

```py
from PIL import Image
import base64

image = Image.open("ptable.png")
bytes = image.tobytes()


mystr = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode()

# _dict = {"bytes": bytes}

newbytes = base64.b64decode(mystr)

image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (image.size), newbytes, "raw")
image.show()
```